# from ascii codepoint of character to wstring

Tags: c++, wstring, codepoint

With code bellow i can take wstring of a codepoint character.
If codepoint>65535 take wrong wstring. How must do it?

```
wstring giveWStringFromASCII(size_t i)
{
    wchar_t character[]= {i,0};
    return wstring(character);
}
```

Comment: Does [`std::u32string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) work for you?

Comment: No, must be wstring from a codepoint > 65535, 0xffff

Comment: ASCII and > 65535? Impossible! You are talking about Unicode?

Comment: No ASCII, only wstring. Function wrong maybe name...

Comment: ASCII is one Byte! The greatest value is 255.

Comment: Ok, let say function  wstring giveWStringFrom_a_number(size_t i) where i >65535  wstring giveWStringFrom_a_number(size_t i)
{
    wchar_t character[]= {i,0};
    return wstring(character);
}

Comment: Ok, let's say you don't know what you are doing. If in your Implementation wchar_t is a short, than you can not fit values greater than 65535 into it. If you have a UTF-32 encoded char you have to convert it to UTF-16 to fit into wstring.

Comment: How must do "*what*"? You wish to "*take wrong wstring*"? What does taking wrong wstring mean? Does the shown code not do that? How does the behaviour of shown code differ from what you intended?

Comment: How  i can have wstring from i>65535 in UTF8 encoded?

Comment: @manni66 -- the greatest value for ASCII is 127; there are a bunch of "extended ASCII" encodings that use values from 128 to 255.

Comment: Please speak in more complete sentences. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @PeteBecker you mean US-ASCII ;)

Comment: If your `wchar_t` is 16 bit and thus your `wstring`s are UTF-16, if you want to fit a code point > 65535 you have to explode it into the so-called surrogate pairs. You should definitely [read about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description).

Comment: @manni66 US- prefix is redundant ;) The A stands for American.

Answer (score 1):

`std::wstring` uses `wchar_t` elements.  `wchar_t` is not portable, as it uses 2 bytes (UTF-16 encoded) on Windows, but uses 4 bytes (UTF-32 encoded) on other platforms.

A Unicode codepoint stored in a `size_t` can be assigned as-is to a `wchar_t` only on non-Windows platforms.  On Windows, a single `wchar_t` can only handle Unicode characters in the BMP (UCS-2) range (U+0000 - U+FFFF).  Higher codepoints must be encoded as 2 `wchar_t` elements, known as a "surrogate pair" in UTF-16.

What you have shown will only work as-is on non-Windows platforms.  If you need to support multiple platforms, you will have to `#ifdef` the code accordingly, eg:

```
std::wstring giveWStringFromCodepoint(size_t cp)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32

    wchar_t ch[2];
    if (cp < 0x10000)
    {
        ch[0] = (wchar_t) cp;
        return std::wstring(ch, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        cp -= 0x10000;
        ch[0] = (wchar_t) ((cp >> 10) + 0xD800);
        ch[1] = (wchar_t) ((cp & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00);
        return std::wstring(ch, 2);
    }

    #else

    wchar_t ch = (wchar_t) i;
    return std::wstring(&ch, 1);

    #endif
}
```

Or:

```
std::wstring giveWStringFromCodepoint(size_t cp)
{
    #if (WCHAR_MAX > 0xFFFF)

    wchar_t ch = (wchar_t) i;
    return std::wstring(&ch, 1);

    #else

    wchar_t ch[2];
    if (cp < 0x10000)
    {
        ch[0] = (wchar_t) cp;
        return std::wstring(ch, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        cp -= 0x10000;
        ch[0] = (wchar_t) ((cp >> 10) + 0xD800);
        ch[1] = (wchar_t) ((cp & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00);
        return std::wstring(ch, 2);
    }

    #endif
}
```

Or:

```
std::wstring giveWStringFromCodepoint(size_t cp)
{
    if (sizeof(wchar_t) > 2)
    {
        wchar_t ch = (wchar_t) i;
        return std::wstring(&ch, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        wchar_t ch[2];
        if (cp < 0x10000)
        {
            ch[0] = (wchar_t) cp;
            return std::wstring(ch, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            cp -= 0x10000;
            ch[0] = (wchar_t) ((cp >> 10) + 0xD800);
            ch[1] = (wchar_t) ((cp & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00);
            return std::wstring(ch, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, you are better off using a 3rd party Unicode library, like ICONV or ICU, to handle this type of conversion for you.

If you are using C++11 or later, it has `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` available to avoid the portability issues of `std::wstring`.  Consider using them when possible.  Or, at least, consider using `std::wstring_convert` when dealing with UTF conversions, if not using a 3rd party library.

Comment: Instead of checking for Windows (which actually would be `#ifdef _WIN32`), I would check for the size of `wchar_t` - it's easier, clearer and more correct.

Comment: You can check the value of `WCHAR_MAX`. `#if WCHAR_MAX == 65535`... `#elif WCHAR_MAX ==  4294967295`... `#else` `#error unsupported wchar_t size` `#endif`.

Comment: Thank's for all. So depends from OS.